# Trigger animation of two elements on hover

Tags: html, css

I made a grid container that does the page organization (for a lack of a better term) one of those blocks is the contact page, the html code for that looks like this:

```
<div class="grid-contact"> <img class="socials" src="facebook.png" alt="fb"> Contact </div>
```

The css code for the div and the img looks like this

```
.grid-contact{
    border: 1px solid black;
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    font-size: 30px;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    text-align: center;
    width: 65px;
    transition: width 0.5s, font-size 0.5s;
}

.socials{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    height: 2.56px;
    width: 2.56px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    right: 2px;
    transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
}
```

I envisioned it so that when you hover over the contact text it's gonna slide out and all the social media logos would kinda get bigger, and I did exactly what I wanted with these two hover css blocks:

```
.grid-contact:hover{
    display: inherit;
    width: 130px;
    font-size: 65px;
}

.socials:hover{
    height: 25.6px;
    width: 25.6px;
}
```

However, I don't know how to trigger both of the animations when just hovering the "Contact" text.

Also the way I figured to do it, with the logos being super small and then just changing their size on hover may be completely wrong but it's the only thing I could think of, if you think there could be an easier solution altogether please let me know. Also I've been learning javascript aswell so if there is a way to do it with js too I'm all ears.

I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem, you can just make something like that:

```
.grid-contact:hover{
    display: inherit;
    width: 130px;
    font-size: 65px;
}
.grid-contact:hover > .socials {
    height: 25.6px;
    width: 25.6px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, it doesn't solve the problem the text "contact" does the animation, but the little icon stays 2.5px and doesnt take on the 25.6px size

Comment: That's very strange...can you post your code in a jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vo0kqxp4/1/ This is even stranger, the alternative text works as imagined, but the image on my live server preview doesn't do the same thing

Comment: Excuse me, I made an error: it's `.socials` and not `socials`

Comment: Please try now and tell me the result

Comment: Yes it works now, thank you so much, could you tell me what you did? I would like to read up on it to understand how it works

Comment: I just used a [css selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp): when the user hovers the div (`.grid-contact:hover`), his child (`> .socials`) changes the height and width. You can learn more about css selectors [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)